# Magento2 Custom Page Layout

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I am newbie with Magento. I want to create Custom CMS Template Page. I have tried bunch of tutorial but does get it proper way. can any body help me?

What I have do I am writing it down here.

For Theme I have created a theme Folder Under app/design/frontend/VM/TM

### Here is code of Theme File

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>VM TM</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
      <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
</media>
</theme>
```

---

Then Registered it with below code

---

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/VM/TM',
__DIR__);
```

---

After It Created Folder Magento_Theme and file layouts.xml with Followind Code

---

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
<layout id="1column">
    <label translate="true">1 column</label>
</layout>
<layout id="2columns-left">
    <label translate="true">2 columns with left bar</label>
</layout>
<layout id="2columns-right">
    <label translate="true">2 columns with right bar</label>
</layout>
<layout id="3columns">
    <label translate="true">3 columns</label>
</layout>
<layout id="values_tpl">
    <label translate="true">Values Template</label>
</layout>
```

---

Thene created a Page Name with Values and selected "Values Template" from Design tab for Values Page.

Then Created page-layout Folder and created a values_tpl.xml with following code

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="1column"/>
</layout>
```

---

and created a layout folder and copy default.xml to values_tpl.xml

but when rendering values CMS page render blanked only background display of my common css. rest page goes blank.. even after copied same as default layout.

I don't know what is going wrong ..can any body help me ?

Thank you in advance.